# Circular Dependency With ActiveRecord Relations in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, yii2, di-containers

I was using ActiveRecord models by defining relationships between them in Yii2 framework. Now I am trying to use dependency injection container with my ActiveRecord models and want to inject my dependencies. But circular dependency issue is confusing me.

If we define our relationships like explained [Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md#working-with-relational-data), won't we end up having circular dependency issue? or I am missing something?

Thanks for any help and pointers.

Edit:
Code Example from my models.

```
class NavMenu extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function getNavItemMenu() {
        return $this->hasOne(NavItemMenu::className(), ['id' => 'nav_item_menu_id' ]);
    }
}


class NavItemMenu extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function getNavMenus() {
        return $this->hasMany(NavMenu::className(), ['nav_item_menu_id' => 'id' ]);
    }
}
```

Above code is simplified just to give you the idea of the problem.

Comment: you trying to write a model file? with all the relation

Comment: What i do is define a relation in mysql database itself and use gii tool to generate model. Then i modify the model. hope this help.
Still newbee to yii2.

Comment: so you need manual relation even if it does not exist in  mysql table or something like that. 
Share some code please and table structure

Answer (score 0):

The anser is in the link you gave us :)

You should add `inverseOf()` to the `getNavMenus()` relation:

```
public function getNavMenus() {
    return $this->hasMany(NavMenu::className(), ['nav_item_menu_id' => 'id' ])
                ->inverseOf('navItemMenu');
}
```